# Feeling that speaker's low bass getting stuck in one's ear

Tags: acoustics, speakers

(The feeling is is subjective, but it is very hard to describe technically.) I have a speaker with very strong bass, which is fine, but when I play music with it, even in **extremely low** volume, it feels as if something gets stuck in my ear, and it is hard to tolerate. It causes headache.

In a real concert (classical or pop or whatever), the sound could be 10 times louder, without any discomfort.

I presume this speaker is designed for people who prefer that (is that heavy-metal??) feeling.

I am trying to understand what's going on here. Questions:

1. How does a speaker manage to create such an impact, making your head resonate, at a **low** volume?
2. Adjusting the balance of high and low frequencies doe not help at all. I need to make the bass barely audible to alleviate the discomfort. That's strange. What is going on?
3. Obviously, the answer to "how to improve this" is "to buy a new speaker". Are there any other ways to change this?

**To clarify, I have emphasized that other speakers and concerts are fine. So I don’t think we should consider other factors such as the room.**

Comment: Does this ability to make your head resonate change between days?

Comment: @Dekkadeci Of course it does not depend on the time. Why do you think it could be time-dependent?

Comment: Well, it could be biological. Meanwhile, I'm wondering about the acoustics of the space in which the speaker is. There are a lot of components here: The device outputting the audio, the speaker itself, the space in which the sound is being produced, and finally your own ear. I'm wondering whether the room has a resonant frequency that's involved. If you can, try the speaker in a different space. Meanwhile, I'm afraid this is more an audio gear issue and isn't [covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); it might be good on [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't belong on Sound Design either. We don't cover consumer audio. One way to test whether it's the speaker or the amp is to change the ratio of how much 'work' each is doing. Send a high signal from the player, turn the amp down - vs send a low signal from the player, with the amp turned up to compensate. That would eliminate any potential 'loudness' control the amp is injecting to compensate for low volume. At low volumes the bass will almost vanish in relation to the higher frequencies, so consumer gear sometimes ramps the bass to compensate.

Comment: You ask about *one* speaker. Have you only the one? Is it the bass woofer? Could you swap over for the other of a pair?  What happens when you listen with cans: is it the same channel that's bass-heavy? We need more info!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about audio gear are off-topic https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Wait what kind of speaker? Also have you tried the same speaker in a different room? Seems like room resonance to me

Comment: @MaJoad because a large number of auditory experiences like that which you describe are 'time dependent', and reliant on something biological. It is, as you say, a subjective experience and I don't think too many will be able to identify with this feeling exactly. Dekkadeci's question is valid as it may point toward something unusual, or something simple, such as excessive wax buildup, or eustachian tube blockage. Not that we can diagnose that here, but the phenomena you describe is not familiar to me even having spent a lifetime dealing manly in sub-bass frequencies :)

Comment: @MaJoad - You say "It causes headache", which leads me to believe this problem is at least part biological (e.g. your head has a resonant frequency? Perhaps that changes with time?) I lost part of my hearing this year with a particularly unfortunate session of picking earwax out of my ears, and it took me weeks to recover.

Comment: @Dekkadeci  Other speakers are fine, so I presume that’s the issue with this speaker.

Comment: We still need to consider the room until we eliminate it from consideration - not by changing the speaker and not the room, but by **changing the room and not the speaker** - i.e. moving the speaker into another room and checking if the same problem occurs.

Comment: What speaker model is it? And have you tried other speakers in the same place in your listening room to compare? All speakers just present frequencies. High quality speakers are able to present all frequencies within a given band very accurately compared to source material. A low quality speaker or compromised listening environment (more the latter) can emphasise certain frequencies and this CAN become uncomfortable, but this is usually a feature of a very small untreated room. If your room is ok, perhaps the placement? Acoustics is a complex field, a speaker a fairly simple device.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes a small speaker achieves the impression of extended bass response by engineering a strong resonance at just one low frequency (yes, I'm looking at you, Bose).    You get bass, but it's always the same note!   Perhaps this is what's happening.

But if one frequency, even at low volume, is causing real discomfort, I think you need to see a doctor.    Also, of course, stop using that speaker!

Comment: Also possible that the room is responsible for the resonance.  Or it could both, resonating at the same frequency- that's a worst case scenario

Answer (score 2):

In small spaces, room resonances can cause your left and right ear to hear the bass with very different levels or phases, creating a wildly unnatural sound.  I can't say for sure that this is what you are experiencing, but it seems like a possibility.  You can verify this by moving around the room and seeing if the effect changes.